# Is Plain Sight dead?

Tags: plain-sight

I can't access the official site, while playing a Steam version there are some servers, but they are all empty (just bots), and seem to be autocreated by someone?

Or is the site problem temporary, and the company that created the game still supports it?

(I don't know if the question matches the site's theme, but perhaps it would be good to state that the game is dead, for future reference)

Comment: It is back online, then plan to move servers to a different host in the next two weeks to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the latest blog post from the Beatnik Games website as of 17 Oct 2010 11:50:36 GMT.

> ### Oh dear…
>
> Oh dear, the company hosting our servers decided to pull the plug on the power on Saturday morning. Unfortunately, we only discovered that everything was down when we got back to the office after the weekend.
> We’re really sorry about this and shall be moving our servers in the next few weeks so this doesn’t happen again.
>
> <sub>Posted by Robin on 10/04 at 10:14 AM - [permalink](http://beatnikgames.co.uk/index.php/beatnik/oh_dear/) - [google cache link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:h_2jXVlm_1IJ:beatnikgames.co.uk/+plain+sight+blog&hl=en&strip=1) - [twitter announcement](http://twitter.com/#!/beatnikgames/status/26350720276)</sub>

It seems like this is happening again... but it doesn't seem like Beatnik is dropping the ball on the game.